# Android: Getting UI elements and there values currently displayed on the screen, from different Application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-source

How can i get GUI components (TextView/Buttons/ListViews) and their values (Data they are currently displaying on screen) from a background service, which is not part of currently running Application.

Any clue of how we can archive this?
Can we do this from application layer or we need to have to go deep in Android source?

Comment: you making a spy app :O

Comment: :) no, not a spy app!

Comment: you'd probably have to go deep in android source (and have root access maybe). Maybe hook with UI thread and get all screen element. I suppose android goes to great lengths to make sure that processes dont just read each other data (process boundaries). but what you can do is take screen shots at regular intervals. Or maybe hook to some events like on focus etc to trigger screenshots

Comment: I feel the same, need to go deep in the Android source code. can i just get data and widgets info and store it some how-some were from UI thread is it that easy, If i edit UI thread code.

Comment: Do you own all the applications which you are trying to get UI elements for?

Comment: NO i don't own all the application for which i am trying to get UI elements, but my app will have root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can access UI element only one Main thread i,e UI Thread.
2. Suppose you are starting the Background Service from IntentService you can use Bundle before starting the service store all the necessary values in bundle and start IntentService(background Service).
3. And retrieve the Values from Bundle and Use it